# OSX Managed Images (Java)

Tags: java, macos, bufferedimage, java-2d

I'm developing a 2D game using Java2D for graphics. I've been getting remarkably bad performance on OSX devices when the same hardware holds at 60 FPS when booted with Windows 7.

I've been doing some investigating and found that, among other issues, Apple doesn't seem to want to manage images.

I added in a line to print out each time an image is drawn-

```
 System.out.println(image.getCapabilities(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()).isAccelerated());
```

On Windows, after like 2 seconds, this is always true. On Mac, no matter how long it runs, this shows as false.

All the images show as TYPE_INT_ARGB, and I'm not performing any image manipulation, it just will not manage. Can anyone provide any advice on how to make OSX manage images?

EDIT:

Here are the System.properties for a mac that I'm testing on:

```
  sun.java2d.opengl=true
  java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
  sun.boot.library.path=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries
  java.vm.version=20.51-b01-456
  awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true
  gopherProxySet=false
  mrj.build=10M4508
  java.vm.vendor=Apple Inc.
  java.vendor.url=http://www.apple.com/
  java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
  sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
  user.country=US
  sun.os.patch.level=unknown
  java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
  java.runtime.version=1.6.0_51-b11-456-10M4508
  java.awt.graphicsenv=apple.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
  java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/endorsed
  os.arch=x86_64
  apple.awt.graphics.UseOpenGL=false
```

Comment: How do you create `image`? What JRE are you using (`java -version`)?

Comment: I get image using` ImageIO` and creating a compatible image using the `BufferedImage target = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleImage` method.

JRE is 1.6 distributed by Apple